# Restrict the rotation of the camera using button

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotation, axis

I've been trying to limit the Y-axis of the camera rotation but I'm out of depth until now. I'd looked up many tutorials and I found the clamping method, but I seem can't get it to work on my code, and all the tutorials I found is using them in Update(), while I'm using a button to rotate the camera. Here's the code:

```
public void RotateLeft()
{
    cameraY = Mathf.Clamp(cameraY, minAngle, maxAngle);
    if(cameraY >= minAngle)
    {
        Camera.main.transform.Rotate(0,-cameraY,0);
    }
}
public void RotateRight()
{
    cameraY = Mathf.Clamp(cameraY, minAngle, maxAngle);
    if(cameraY <= maxAngle)
    {
        Camera.main.transform.Rotate(0,cameraY,0);
    }
}
```

Does clamping works outside an Update()? What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. Thanks to [this Unity Question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/861191/what-should-i-do-to-limit-rotation-on-z-axis-c.html) though..

```
public void RotateLeft()
{
    myRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(myRotation.y - 1f, -45f, 45f);
    Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(myRotation);
}
public void RotateRight()
{
    myRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(myRotation.y + 1f, -45f, 45f);
    Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(myRotation);
}
```